# Evaluating an expression tree without a stack

Tags: algorithm, tree, stack

Is it possible to evaluate an expression tree (pre/postfix) without using a stack? Had this question while talking about trees in the algorithm class at school. My guess is no.

Comment: Have you thought about using a recursive approach?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: hem, without a stack.

Comment: Can you show us how you evaluate the tree using a stack? I am a little bit confused.

Comment: @Eidbanger: In the general case you need temporary storage proportional to the depth of the tree though it does not necessarily need to be arranged as an explicit stack data structure, such as how compilers for the most part flatten the trees to register machine instructions. Whether you chose to view the flattened computation as an implicit stack is a question of definition, and frankly not terribly interesting.

Comment: An expression tree dis not 'prefix/postfix'. It is pre/post/in-order, usually the latter.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can.

Do a [breadth first traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) of the tree (like a search, but do through all the tree). You can do this with a vector/queue/list in a iterative way.

Once you are done you can go backwards through the list/vector/queue you generated in the previous step. At each point compute the value of the node in the list. Since you have all the children already visited (you are going backwards) all you have to do is to lookup their value and apply the instructions in the node.

Comment: This is completely equivalent to using a stack.